# Text formating with CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd, styled-components

I am using the ant-design library with the Table and Tooltip component

I am trying to format the tooltip so that each element inside of my array is on it's own line instead of 1 big paragraph like how it is here.

The code that generates the above UI looks like this

```
const generateTableColumns = () => {
    if (survey) {
      const selectedSurvey = `${survey}`.toLowerCase()
      const columnHeaders = SurveyArray[selectedSurvey].questions.map(item => ({
        title: item.id,
        dataIndex: item.id,
        key: item.id,
        ellipsis: {
          showTitle: false,
        },
        render: dataIndex => (
          <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={dataIndex}>
            {dataIndex}
          </Tooltip>
        ),
      }))
      setTableColumns(columnHeaders)
    }
  }
```

I have tried doing

```
render: dataIndex => (
          <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={dataIndex}>
            { {_.isArray(dataIndex) ? dataIndex.map(item => <p className="test">{item}</p>) : null} }
          </Tooltip>
        ),
```

Which formats the elements in the table, not the tooltip.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can style the elements inside of the span like I did on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render: dataIndex => (
          <Tooltip
            placement="topLeft"
            title={
              _.isArray(dataIndex) ? dataIndex.map(item => <p className="test">{item}</p>) : null
            }
          >
            {dataIndex}
          </Tooltip>
        ),
```

From reading the docs, looks like `title` is what is being used to render the elements inside of the tooltip. This gave me what I was after

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use "\n" to break line.

```
"Hi, my name is Emir." => "Hi, my name is Emir."
"Hi, \n my name is Emir." =>
"Hi,
 my name is Emir."
```

Note: I'm not sure about the answer I wish I could add this as a comment but my reputation is not enough to comment. Have a nice day!